# Uninstalling and reinstalling Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I manually installed Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 then simply deleted the folder where I put the Eclipse and reinstalled it again from the Ubuntu application store.

When I try to update my new installation I get the following error.

How can I do a clean nuinstalation and reinstallation?

An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.platform_root 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file /usr/lib/eclipse/.eclipseproduct failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: /usr/lib/eclipse/.eclipseproduct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try to delete file /usr/lib/eclipse/.eclipseproduct as root?

```
sudo rm  /usr/lib/eclipse/.eclipseproduct
```

Comment: How can actually view the contents of "usr" directory? (I guess this is a hidden directory)

Comment: using terminal you could type in "ls /usr" without quotes and it will echo the contents of this directory. If you're going to type the command above remember to type it **exactly** as I've shown, because it deletes files from system directory and it can get messy if you delete something unwanted. To see contents in Nuatilus got to root directory / and usr directory will be there.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove it using Ubuntu's uninstaller (deleting manually as necessary) and then install Eclipse downloaded from eclipse.org. I never use the Eclipse that comes with the Linux distros.

Comment: Why you hate installing Eclipse from Ubuntu app store? I preferred it because it puts an Eclipse icon in the launcher.

Comment: Also installing software by package manager (so also by using app store) makes it easier to have a clean system - it is easy to uninstall packages later, and see what packages are installed. Installing software "by hand" creates clutter - you may easily forget what you've installed, where and when, you won't automatically get updates and you loose all the benefits of using a package manager. So I'd recommend to do it only as an last resort.